# Cannot download my test app on ios using firebase app-distribution and Expo

Tags: ios, firebase, testing, expo, app-distribution

I'm experiencing this issue: I'm developing on windows an app with Expo and I'd like to share it for test to my team, but while I had no problems with android devices, it is not possible to download it from ios.
I'm using Expo as framework and Firebase app distribution to share the builds, I already create a new profile with certificate and add the udid of the ios devices to it, I try just by re-building the app without change version number but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?
I'm attaching an image to help.
[this is the release page where i should be able to download the app, it said that is waiting for a new distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geV8N.jpg)

As you may guess this is my first time developing on mobile.
Hope I gave you all the info,
thanks

i tried building the first time but eventually i discovered that i had to add the UDID of apple devices, after I added them, i saw my profile was the wrong one, so i create another one in ios app development mode adding the devices, that i made another build expecting to solve the problem but it didn't work, i thought the new profile was added automatically to the build, it is so?

Comment: *firebaser here* Not sure if this is affecting you, but I just heard that CLI version 13.2 has an issue with *uploading* releases to app distro. See https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/4z5LT9V6m66HCt1BWWDv The engineering team is working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

So after having this issue as well and a couple of hours of investigation
I think the root cause of what is happening for you is that when you create the build you don't create it as an adhoc build, if you are using an eas.json file with profiles you will need to add this

```
"profile": {
  "distribution": "internal",
  "ios": {
    "enterpriseProvisioning": "adhoc"
},
```

Afterwards you will need to register the UUIDS with expo, it is not enough to have them on the appstoreconnect portal and you will need to create them in expo as well.

```
expo device:create
```

you will be promted to add them, you can have expo import it from the appstoreconnect if you allowed it to and than you can just import the builds and use them in the adhoc internal build

one caveat that I was having is that when I tried to create the build I was getting an error from expo that it couldn't provision profiles and I solved it by going into expo console -> your project -> credentials -> deleted the provision profile downloaded it from appstore connect and re uploaded it to expo.

Than everything worked just fine

Happy coding